# How do I make Cucumber go to the next annotation only after the previous one has returned its async requests?

Tags: javascript, selenium, cross-browser, cucumber, chai

I want to create a simple test with Seleinium and Cucumber to login to my webapp and then verify that all is as it should be on the main page. All three tests immediately return true even before the page has been fetched, but the When step fails to find the input element because it begins before the get request has been completed. I'm new to this framework so I could be doing everything completely wrong.

```
const capabilities = {
  browserName: 'IE',
  browser_version: '11.0',
  os: 'Windows',
  os_version: '10',
  resolution: '1024x768',
  'browserstack.user': 'henry',
  'browserstack.key': 'pass',
  name: 'Bstack-[Node] Sample Test'
};

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .usingServer('http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub')
  .withCapabilities(capabilities)
  .build();


Given('The login page loads', () => {
  driver.get('https://example.com/').then(() => {
    driver.getTitle().then((title) => {
      expect(title).to.eql('My webapp');
    });
  });
});

When('I login', () => {
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('username')).sendKeys('henry@example.com');
});

Then('I should see the dashboard', () => {

});
```

```
Feature: Login
  Login to the Petasense webapp
  Scenario: Scenario name
      Given The login page loads
      When I login
      Then I should see the dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use wait before performing any action. For e.g

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id1")),
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id2"))
));
```

Or use sleep before next step. e.g

```
Thread.sleep
```